# What's our status in voting?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, answer-quality, votes

The most upvoted answer in the questionnaire in the recent moderator election, pointed out two issues:

- U&L is way below average among SE sites when it comes to questions with at least one upvoted answers
- not everyone shares this impression of being welcomed

The second one is a highly subjective matter, but the first one can be quantified and verified with hard data. So, I <s>stole</s> borrowed from [rolf](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8575/169736) one of his queries to measure the [activity of the site](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph#graph) and here's the result:

[image]

As you can see, our votes on answers is normally greater than commenting and votes on questions are half way there. There are other healthy pieces of information, like the amount of answers is normally higher than the amount of questions in a proportion 5:4 (answers per questions) which is good, and some sites have problems to even keep up. Now, I compared this with Ask Ubuntu and Super User, as they are the most technically nearest SE sites to us, and here's the results:

[image: Super User]

[image: Ask Ubuntu]

I took the same period of time (last 104 weeks) for all charts.

So, what do we see here?

- We do vote more than commenting on posts (which is a good thing IMO, since the main type of feedback should be in votes, no comments), contrary to our other counterparts which languish proportionally.
- We have proportionally more votes on questions/answers per individual Q/A than SU and AU.

At least those two, we have way better standing than the other similar sites. What everyone else think?

Comment: Excellent work! Thanks for putting this together. I always like hard data vs. opinion(s), less to argue with 8-).

Comment: Very nice. It is good we did not get an influx of new users as pronounced as SU early June, that could have given the impression someone was buying voters ;-). But it does seem the election-related chatting dragged people away from commenting on U&L